# XML парсинг PHP

Tags: xml, xmlparser, php

Вот допустим `XML` документ:

```
<node>
    <testnode>
        <xmlll x1="test1" x2="test2">
    </testnode>
</node>
```

Мне нужно пропарсить на `PHP` так чтобы узнать и вывести на экран `test1` и `test2`, файл `test.xml`. Как такое реализовать, нигде не найду внятного ответа.

И еще второй случай, когда так:

```
<node>
<xmlll x1="test1" x2="test2">
</node>
```

Comment: simple_xml пробовали рассмотреть?

Comment: да, вообще ничего не понял, я привел два XML документа test.xml дайте, пожалуйста 2 кода, для первого и для второго, чтобы шел вывод test1 и test2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<node>
    <testnode>
        <xmlll x1="test1" x2="test2" />
    </testnode>
</node>');

echo $xml->testnode[0]->xmlll[0]['x1'];
```

То есть, `$xml` содержит весь документ (корень, то есть, элемент `<node>`); `->testnode` содержит **1** узел `<testnode>`, который, в свою очередь, содержит **1** узел `<xmlll>`.

Если бы, к примеру, XML выглядел так:

```
<node>
    <testnode>
        <xmlll x1="test1" x2="test2" />
        <xmlll x1="test1111" x2="test2222" />
    </testnode>
</node>
```

то добраться до атрибута `x1` второго узла `<xmlll>` (получить "test1111") можно так:

```
echo $xml->testnode[0]->xmlll[1]['x1'];  // test1111
```